# Is there any workaround for "session deleted because of page crash" Chrome error on Travis CI?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, docker, travis-ci

I'm using container-based infrastructure on Travis CI (so I can't use sudo) and I'm trying to run tests using Selenium (Protractor) on the latest Chrome stable. When I try to run the tests, I'm getting this error: `session deleted because of page crash` and all tests fail.

I found that one of the possible issues might be too small `/dev/shm`, which seems to be common when running Chrome on docker (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522853). It looks like there are some workarounds for Travis CI, but they all require sudo.

Are there any workarounds for containers on Travis?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only workaround at the moment is to use Trusty image (via `sudo: required, dist: trusty` in `.travis.yml` file). The Chromium issue mentioned in my question has already been fixed and should land in Chrome 49 (currently Canary), but I'm not sure if it's going to work in docker container anyway.