# Protractor/Selenium running in WMWare Failed: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor, vmware, selenium-chromedriver

Our protractor tests have been recently stopped working with an error I can't reproduce in my dev machine/env, but seems to be regularly occurring on the Jenkins build / test machines which run in VMWare (ESxI) environments.

The error occuring is this:

```
18:05:17 [18:05:09] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
18:05:17 [18:05:09] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
18:05:17 Started
18:05:17 
18:05:17  JASMINE STARTING: 
18:05:17 
18:05:17 
18:05:17 Â»  Main App Test
18:05:17 [31mF[0m   âœ—  App Module Test  (1 s)
18:05:17        - Failed: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
18:05:17 from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
18:05:17 from tab crashed
18:05:17   (Session info: content shell=)
18:05:17   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
18:05:17 Command duration or timeout: 266 milliseconds
18:05:17 Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
18:05:17 System info: host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', ip: '99.99.99.99', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
18:05:17 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
18:05:17 Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b), userDataDir=C:\Users\RABUIL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6264_14292}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
18:05:17 Session ID: 8ba3690dfc0ab400933236ae8eefd5ee
```

I scoured the forums and found several other issues related to this error occurring on docker and tmux configurations. The essence of the resolutions were that the environment could be tweaked to allow some extra resources to be accessed for the Chrome driver so that it would be able to complete its work. For example :

http://borkweb.com/story/chromedriver-doesnt-run-in-tmux

[Selenium: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714948/selenium-unknown-error-session-deleted-because-of-page-crash)

[Is there any workaround for "session deleted because of page crash" Chrome error on Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753613/is-there-any-workaround-for-session-deleted-because-of-page-crash-chrome-error)

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/731

(the list goes on)..

What is frustrating is that this is a test set that has been working for many weeks, and it now crashes. It **never** fails on a non-VMWare environment. Trying to piece together any clues that might help. Does anyone think that it might be a problem with the Chrome driver running in a Windows WMWare environment akin to the problems seen on tmux and docker situations?

I see some hints of this being a possibility on other posts (also without a resolution) here:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22707/selenium-chromedriver-in-virtual-machine

As I said, I've scoured the stackoverflow and other forums and found little to point me in a clear direction.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, tests that worked perfectly for months switched to run on vmware and started randomly crash. Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the previous answer is only beneficial in some situations that allow your test machine to keep the `protractor` and `selenium` software installed. Additionally, the `page crash` error would still seem to occur in occasional situations when resources or slowness on the machine seemed to hamper the operation of the build and tests. Keep in mind that we were taking the approach that our goal  was to have the entire process (build, packaging, unit tests, and end-to-end tests) all complete in a nightly build process.  After lots of wrangling with tweaks to both the machine and protractor, we decided that it was a priority to return to completely cleaning up the build machine after each build (including removing the tools used in the end-to-end tests/protractor).

This, then, is a 2nd solution to the problem that may prove to be better if your goals are the same as ours (solution 1, above, may prove better for others).

- **STEP 1**: configure protractor to use the `directConnect` option in the config file.
- **STEP 2**: install protractor locally as part of your package.
- **STEP 3**: update the webdriver as a post-step to the install.
- **STEP 4**: execute protractor from your local project `node_modules`, not from a global install.

To accomplish STEP 1, your `protractor.conf.js` should have the `direcConnect` option turned on, as in:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
...
...
...
```

To accomplish STEPs 2-4, your `package.json` file should have a `scripts` section with these two lines in it (in addition to whatever else you need in scripts):

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "TIMEOUT /T 10 && node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "TIMEOUT /T 10 && node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor \"protractor.conf.js\""
  },
```

The `devDependencies` section of your `package.json` file should have protractor being installed locally, as in:

```
  "devDependencies": {
...
...
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
...
...
  }
```

Since making these changes, we no longer have any issues with the original "page crash" error.

Answer (score 0):

This was our first attempt to find a workaround to this issue, which avoided the problem, but doesn't seem like a solution to the crash itself in the original context. First, some brief background. The package.json for our protractor project included the following:

```
 "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm install -g protractor",
    "postinstall": "webdriver-manager update",
    "pretest": "start \"SeleniumServer\" webdriver-manager start",
    "test": "TIMEOUT /T 10 && protractor \"protractor.conf.js\"",
    "posttest": "TIMEOUT /T 10 && webdriver-manager shutdown"
  },
```

(We are running on Windows, so these exact `package.json` scripts may vary slightly with your OS).

Upon completion of `npm test` in our build process, we would run `npm install -g protractor` to wrap up the end-to-end tests and their footprint on the build machine. The reason we took this approach is so that the build machine (into which this protractor project was running) would be kept clean from protractor, since we didn't want it impacting the environment.

The workaround that we employed is to now have protractor fully installed on the machine permanently and be sure to not include the install/uninstall of it in the build process.  The pertinent section of our `package.json` scripts section now looks like this.

```
 "scripts": {
    "pretest": "start \"SeleniumServer\" webdriver-manager start",
    "test": "TIMEOUT /T 10 && protractor \"protractor.conf.js\"",
    "posttest": "TIMEOUT /T 10 && webdriver-manager shutdown"
  },
```

Secondarily, we added (as you can see) timeouts to wait for selenium server to start up fully, the tests to complete fully and then the selenium server to shutdown fully.  The waits given in the hooked lifecycle of the pretest/test/posttest synch of the commands do not account for how windows actually runs, so we had to use the `start` command to launch a separate window and our own native `TIMEOUT` calls.

What we found in the end was that it seems that VM Ware constrains the resources unpredictably on build process machines and you simply have to componentize the tasks to the point of isolating any extra things that could hang or slow down your protractor tests when they are running.

**For some reason, installing protractor just before running tests always seemed like a good way to get them to fail on a regular basis**. We removed that risk, which makes sense in hindsight, but was originally done to keep it from dirtying up the build machine with test packages.

Hope that makes sense and helps others.